# Cинонимы к слову "влияние"

Tags: трудности, грамматика

Добрый вечер,
Прошу вашей помощи!Мне необходимо найти синонимы к слову "влияние", требуется в четырех предложениях данная замена. "Воздействие" не очень удачно сочетается по смыслу, так как текст научный, точнее диссертация( оглавление). 
Спасибо!
Ирина.
Можно ответить по эл. почте: irena-kuz@mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то точных синонимов, вроде, нет.

*Контекстные: Влияние, действие, воздействие, давление, обаяние, возбуждение. .... Ср. Внушение, Возбуждение, Действие.*
(gramota.ru)

Напишите Ваши предложения, по контексту что-то, возможно, удастся придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Действие, воздействие, роль.

Возможно так:

1. Классификация факторов, влияющих на качество жизни.
2. Роль социальных факторов в  повышении  качества жизни населения.
3. Экономические кризисы  и   уровень  жизни населения
4. Зависимость политической активности граждан от  социальной дифференциации.
5. Влияние качества жизни на политическую активность населения.
6. Средства массовой информации как инструмент воздействия на политическое поведение граждан. (по-моему, удачно заменили)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день,
Спасибо всем, кто мне ответил. Согласна, что лучше исходя из контекста. Мои предложения следующие:
 1. Классификация факторов, влияющих на качество жизни.
 2. Социальные факторы, влияющие на качество жизни.
 3. Влияние экономических кризисов на качество жизни населения( заменила на воздействие)
 4. Влияние социальной дифференциации на политическую активность
 5. Влияние качества жизни на политическую активность населения
 6. Влияние средств массовой информации на политическое поведение граждан( заменила на средства массовой информации как инструмент воздействия на политическое поведение граждан).
 Предложения можно изменить, но смысл сохранить необходимо.
Спасибо. Ирина

Comment: Тут, боюсь, будет крайне сложно что-то предложить, не пожертвовав ни смыслом, ни стилем.  
У Вас все вхождения соответствуют одному значению "влияния" так что идея с заменой на разные по контексту значения по не проходит.

Воздействие, связь (причинно-следственная), зависимость, роль и проч. - даёт лишь очень приблизительное соответствие. Но тут важно понять, насколько в Вашем тексте слово "влияние" терминологизировано. Если Вы за буквальный смысл не держитесь, то попробуйте хотя бы то, что предлагает Людмила.